# Log all errors and warnings

Tags: node.js, logging, console.log, error-logging, winston

I am using a third party nodejs application which is quite large and it is using many different things for logging. For instance `console.log()` and `console.error()`. I would like to be able to trap all output and log to a specific file. I was thinking about using `winston` and do something like this:

```
const winston = require('winston')
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'error.log', level: 'error' })
  ]
})

const ce = console.error
console.error = function(...args) {
  logger.log.apply('error', args)
  ce.apply(args)
}
```

Is there a better way to handle this kind of situation?

I might also add that some parts of the application is already using `winston` for logging purposes.

My aim is the create a single file with all errors and warnings generated from within the application.